# Using parsley on a wizard form (3 steps)

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, twitter-bootstrap, parsley.js

I'm working on a form based on a Twitter Bootstrap tab.

I use Parsley for validation form.

I would like to validate only the fields on my first tab (step 1) before clicking on the next button that go to step 2.

Is there a way to do that? Cheers.

Answer (score 9):

You can also add an **event listener** to parsley that checks if the element is visible or not.
If is not visible it will not apply the validation. This way your controls on the invisible tabs are not validated.

```
$( '#form' ).parsley( 'addListener', {
    onFieldValidate: function ( elem ) {

        // if field is not visible, do not apply Parsley validation!
        if ( !$( elem ).is( ':visible' ) ) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
} );
```

**Update:**
Instead of checking for the visibility of the element, you can use whatever condition you may need. For example checking if the element has a specific class.

Example suggested by davidtheclark:

```
$( elem ).closest('.form-page').hasClass('is-hidden')
```

Comment: I'll add in here that, in case it wasn't clear to any reader, you can replace that test `!$(elem).is(':visible')` with whatever will work with your specific form. For instance, I just used this answer for my form but changed the test to `$( elem ).closest('.form-page').hasClass('is-hidden')`. Now I'm quite happy with Parsley!

Comment: See my question on GitHub: https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/issues/1223

Answer (score 3):

If your fields on second tab are hidden, you could just add ':hidden' property to the 'excludedFields' option. That way, each $(yourform).parsley('validate') would only validate visible fields (ie step1 then step2)

If you do so, remember that you will have to manually bind parsley to your form and not with the data-validate="parsley"

Answer (score 2):

If your entire form is loaded in the DOM, and you are able to use the parsely API, you can run multiple validations, one for each step of your wizard. To do that you must use the parsley-bind attribute. Something like:

```
<form action="#">

    <!-- wizard step 1 --> 
    <div class='step1' parsley-validate parsley-bind>
       <input type="text" ..... />
       <input type="text" ..... />
    </div>

    <!-- wizard step 2 --> 
    <div class='step2' parsley-validate parsley-bind>
       <input type="text" ..... />
       <input type="text" ..... />
    </div>

    <!-- wizard step 3 --> 
    <div class='step1' parsley-validate parsley-bind>
       <input type="text" ..... />
       <input type="text" ..... />
    </div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
function onValidate(){

    if(!$('##formID').parsley( 'isValid' )){

        $('.parsley-error').closest('.tab-pane').show();
        return false;

    }

    return true;

 }
</script>    
<form data-validate="parsley" onSubmit="return onValidate()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code by @nmoliveira, updated for Parsley 2.1+:

```
$('form').parsley().on('field:validate', function() {
    var elem = this.$element;

    // If the field is not visible, do not apply Parsley validation!
    if ( !$( elem ).is( ':visible' ) ) {
        this.constraints = [];
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

API has changed a lot in Parsley 2.0.

There's an [official example](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/examples/multisteps.html) on a good way to achieve this.